# Simple Mysql query running slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `MySQL` query that is very simple but is running very slow. I have two table `corporate_main_member` and `corporate_main_corporate_membership` and I am running the following query:

```
SELECT m.gender FROM corporate_main_member m, corporate_main_corporate_membership cm where m.id = cm.FK_member_ID and cm.FK_corporation_id = 6
```

When I don't include second condition`(cm.FK_corporation_id = 6)` , the query runs OK....

Comment: Create an index on FK_corporation_id.

Comment: it would also be interesting to know how much data is in those 2 tables?

Comment: What's "slow"? Have you tried running sub-parts of this query and timing those as well? That could help you identify where the bottleneck is.

Comment: The tables are huge. tens of thousands of rows. fk_corporation_id column is causing problem. Please can you tell me how to add index on this column as it has already an index (foreign key) so it is giving error

Comment: You can use the Execution Plan command to evaluate the query weight

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` Keyword in the query and Create an index on FK_corporation_id.

```
SELECT m.gender 
FROM   corporate_main_member m 
       INNER JOIN corporate_main_corporate_membership cm 
               ON m.id = cm.fk_member_id 
WHERE  cm.fk_corporation_id = 6
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  fk_corporation_id is a foreign key. Can we add another index on it? I am beginner so sorry for this simple question

Comment: Yes, you can add non clustered index on any column (on FK in your case) if a clustered index (PK) is already defined in table.

Comment: adding index did not solve the problem. On another computer with same database the query is executing alright

Comment: what about the machine configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is more efficient form of the above query.

```
SELECT 
m.gender 
FROM corporate_main_member m,
 corporate_main_corporate_membership cm on(m.id = cm.FK_member_ID)
where cm.FK_corporation_id = 6
```

While you can create an index on corporate_main_corporate_membership.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  m.gender
FROM corporate_main_member AS m
  LEFT JOIN corporate_main_corporate_membership AS cm
ON m.id = cm.FK_member_ID
    AND cm.FK_corporation_id = 6
```